# jquery not firing in firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox

My below jQuery is working fine in Safari and Chrome (Latest versions on Mac) but not in Firefox. Any ideas?

```
$('#contact').click(function() 
{

    event.preventDefault(event);

    $("#contact_box").fadeTo("slow", 0.01, function()
     { 
         $(this).slideUp("slow", function() 
         { 
             $(this).remove(); 
         });
     });

    $('.menu_item_content').prepend('<div class="menu_box" id="contact_box"><div class="close_menu_item"id="close_contact_box"><img src="images/close.png" width="30" height="30" alt="X"></div><div class="menu_item_content">who? <b>mrdirty</b> where? <b>mostlydirtyalwaysfresh.com</b></div></div>');

    $('#contact_box').slideDown('slow', function()
    { 
        $(this).fadeTo('slow', 1, function() 
        { 
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the event object into your click handler function:

```
$('#contact').click(function(event)
```